# SVG text getting cut off

Tags: css, svg

When I have a simple svg like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text style="font-size: 24px;">Sample Title</text>
    <text style="font-size: 12px;">Sample Subtitle</text>
</svg>
```

The words are cut off as if it is extending past the top of the viewport like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAN4Z.png

If I add y="24" to the title text tag and y="36" to the subtitle text tag (where y has to be >= the font size), then it is not cut off: https://i.stack.imgur.com/beoee.png

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't include the `y` attribute then it defaults to 0. If you draw the text with a y position of 0, then its baseline is at the top of the image and you'll only see the letter that hang below the baseline.

SVG is primarily a language for describing graphics, so all elements are position with (x, y) coordinates, as opposed to HTML, which is markup language so text flows more naturally.

Comment: Is it possible to change the baseline? If so, is it best practice to set the y on all child elements? Or to change the baseline?

Comment: I've update my answer a bit. With SVG you'll have to set the y value. You can change the `alignment-baseline` attribute to `hanging` so the text will be at the top of the image (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline). But you'll probably want to set the y attribute too.

Comment: If I'm generating SVGs and I don't know if the title will take up multiple lines or not, how can I set the y for subtitle so that it doesn't overlap? Maybe I should put this in a separate question..

Comment: You should know if you have multiple lines or not since text doesn't wrap in SVG, so the number of lines is equal to the number of text elements. Generally it's tricky to do a lot of text arrangement with SVG and you'll need to use JS. It might be work creating a new question with more details so we can see what you're trying to achieve.